# XPath/XSL: produce a clean table through a single for-each loop

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

Probably a really simple question, but I want to produce a clean table through using a single for-each loop in my XSL file using Xpath. I've come a long way, which lead to the resulting file and image you can see below.[image: Like this]

**XSL file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
 <body>
    
  <h2>Provincies</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Provincie</th>
      <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Gemeente</th>
      <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Stad</th>
      <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Aantal bedrijven</th>
    </tr>
                
    <xsl:for-each select="bedrijven/provincie/gemeente/stad">
    <xsl:variable name="provincie" select="../../@naam"/>
    <xsl:variable name="gemeente" select="../@naam"/>
    <xsl:variable name="stad" select="@naam"/>
       <tr>
          <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="preceding::*/text() != $provincie"><td></td></xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise><td><xsl:value-of select="$provincie"/></td></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        
          <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*/text() != $gemeente"><td></td></xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise><td><xsl:value-of select="$gemeente"/></td></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="$stad"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="count(child::bedrijf)"/></td>
       </tr>

   </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the issue is that it only prints the first Province and not the others. I only want every province to be printed once, no repetition. I've been trying to do this all day, and googling all over the place, but I can't seem to find an answer. So I hope someone here can help me. Below is my XML file.

**Example of XML structure**

```
<bedrijven
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:\Users\Boro\Documents\XML opdrachten\XML Opdrachten\Opdracht 1\db\test.xsd">
   <provincie naam="Drenthe">
       <gemeente naam="aa en Hunze">
           <stad naam="anloo">
              <bedrijf>
                  <naam>v.o.f. Anloo</naam>
                  <postcode>9468CG</postcode>
              </bedrijf>
           </stad>
           <stad naam="gasselternijveen">
              <bedrijf>
                  <naam>podiumdelen.nl</naam>
                  <postcode>9514BV</postcode>
              </bedrijf>
           </stad>
        </gemeente>
    </provincie>
    <provincie naam="Flevoland">
        <gemeente naam="almere">
           <stad naam="almere">
               <bedrijf>
                   <naam>mood media</naam>
                   <postcode>1322CE</postcode>
               </bedrijf>
               <bedrijf>
                   <naam>dutch Meat Service</naam>
                   <postcode>1311XC</postcode>
               </bedrijf>
               <bedrijf>
                   <naam>jossafety</naam>
                   <postcode>1338XX</postcode>
               </bedrijf>
           </stad>
        </gemeente>
    </provincie>
</bedrijven>
```

Comment: Well, your input seems to have the structure of separate `provincie` and `gemeente`, so process these elements and map them to the output (e.g. `tbody` and/or `tr` with `td rowspan="{count(gemeente)}"` and inside `td rowspan="{count(stad)}"`. It doesn't make sense to start processing at a deeply nested element like `stad` if the outer structure needs to represented in the result.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hmmm I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you perhaps elaborate? Gemeente (municipality) is a child of provincie (province), so I'm not sure what you mean by them having different structures. Also maybe I should specify that my only remaining objective is to print the name of each province only once, I don't really want to do anymore counting or anything else besides that because everything else is in working condition already.

Comment: Well, if your input XML has a single provinicie with `Drenthe` and a further single provinicie for each distinct provinice you want to output I would strongly suggest to start processing `provinicie` (I would use `apply-templates` but of course you can use `for-each`). Then collect that name and process the underlying `gemeente`, then process the underlying `stad`. No need to struggle around with preceding comparison.

Comment: Instead of writing "etc..." at the end of your XML input, it would be useful to us if you provide a minimal amount of XML input in order to test the code we try to debug.

Comment: You are comparing variables with the values of attributes(@naam) with text() values. I.e. : preceding::*/text() != $provincie. Try in stead this : preceding::*/@naam!= $provincie as a start

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Tried that, leads to the same result. Only prints the first result and no others sadly.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Sorry about that, thought that would be sufficient. I'll update the example for you.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I could do that, but I would prefer to know how to get it working through use of a single for-each loop if possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:variable name="gemeente-pos">
    <xsl:number level="any" from="provincie"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="stad-pos">
    <xsl:number/>
</xsl:variable>

   <tr>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$gemeente-pos != 1"><td></td></xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise><td><xsl:value-of select="$provincie"/></td></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$stad-pos != 1"><td></td></xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise><td><xsl:value-of select="$gemeente"/></td></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="$stad"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="count(child::bedrijf)"/></td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! Thank you very much! I'm still curious how it would work with the setup I did originally, but I'm very glad to have a solution that works :)

Answer (score 1):

I get a correct output with this piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="bedrijven">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Provincies</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Provincie</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Gemeente</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Stad</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Aantal bedrijven</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="provincie">
            <xsl:variable name="provincie" select="@naam"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="gemeente">
              <xsl:variable name="gemeente" select="@naam"/>
              <xsl:for-each select="stad">
                <xsl:variable name="stad" select="@naam"/>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:if 
                      test="count(preceding::stad[
                        ancestor::provincie/@naam = $provincie
                      ]) = 0">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$provincie"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:if 
                      test="count(preceding::stad[
                        ancestor::gemeente/@naam = $gemeente
                      ]) = 0">                       
                      <xsl:value-of select="$gemeente"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$stad"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(child::bedrijf)"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use three levels of `<xsl:for-each>` to avoid recomputing `$provincie` and `$gemeente` in each iteration.

I use a simple test to see if the field `provincie` or `gemeente` corresponds to the first `stad` inside of a `provincie` or a `gemeente`. If it is the first occurence (which means the count of the preceding ones is zero), I print its value.

Martin Ronnen suggests in its comment above to take advantage from the HTML attribute `rowspan` in outputting the results. If you like that idea, you could modify the code in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="bedrijven">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Provincies</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Provincie</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Gemeente</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Stad</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Aantal bedrijven</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="provincie">
            <xsl:variable name="provincie" select="@naam"/>
            <xsl:variable name="steden-per-provincie" 
              select="count(gemeente/stad)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="gemeente">
              <xsl:variable name="gemeente" select="@naam"/>
              <xsl:variable name="steden-per-gemeente" select="count(stad)"/>
              <xsl:for-each select="stad">
                <xsl:variable name="stad" select="@naam"/>
                <tr>
                  <xsl:if 
                    test="count(preceding::stad[
                      ancestor::provincie/@naam = $provincie
                    ]) = 0">
                    <td rowspan="{$steden-per-provincie}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$provincie"/>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if 
                    test="count(preceding::stad[
                      ancestor::gemeente/@naam = $gemeente
                    ]) = 0">                       
                  <td rowspan="{$steden-per-gemeente}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$gemeente"/>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$stad"/>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:right">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(child::bedrijf)"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a screenshot of the result using the `rowspan` attribute:
[image: XSLT output]

If you really need a single `for-each` loop, try this, but it will be less optimal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="bedrijven">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Provincies</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Provincie</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Gemeente</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Stad</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Aantal bedrijven</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="//stad">
            <xsl:variable name="provincie" select="ancestor::provincie/@naam"/>
            <xsl:variable name="gemeente" select="ancestor::gemeente/@naam"/>
            <xsl:variable name="stad" select="@naam"/>
            <tr>
              <xsl:if 
                test="count(preceding::stad[
                  ancestor::provincie/@naam = $provincie
                ]) = 0">
              <td rowspan="{count(following::stad[
                  ancestor::provincie/@naam = $provincie
                ]) + 1}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$provincie"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if 
                test="count(preceding::stad[
                  ancestor::gemeente/@naam = $gemeente
                ]) = 0">                       
              <td rowspan="{count(following::stad[
                  ancestor::gemeente/@naam = $gemeente
                ]) + 1}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$gemeente"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:if>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$stad"/>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:right">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(child::bedrijf)"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And, finally, if you want to use the `xsl:number` feature, here you have a version of the code which is perhaps easier to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="bedrijven">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Provincies</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Provincie</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Gemeente</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Stad</th>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32" style="text-align:left">Aantal bedrijven</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="//stad">
            <xsl:variable name="provincie" select="ancestor::provincie/@naam"/>
            <xsl:variable name="gemeente" select="ancestor::gemeente/@naam"/>
            <xsl:variable name="stad" select="@naam"/>
            <xsl:variable name="gemeente-nr">
              <xsl:number count="gemeente" from="provincie"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="stad-nr">
              <xsl:number count="stad" from="gemeente"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <tr>
              <xsl:if test="($gemeente-nr = 1) and ($stad-nr = 1)">
                <td rowspan="{count(ancestor::provincie//stad)}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$provincie"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="$stad-nr = 1">                       
                <td rowspan="{count(ancestor::gemeente//stad)}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$gemeente"/>
                </td>
              </xsl:if>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="$stad"/></td>
              <td style="text-align:right">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(child::bedrijf)"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, this does indeed seem to work perfectly. If you could be bothered, would you be willing to show me how to get it working in a single for-each loop? Really curious to see what the solution would be :)

Comment: @borovanhout: See my edited answer above.